# CasperJS not loading page

Tags: javascript, casperjs

So, I've gotten this script to work on certain sites, but not the one I'm attempting to get working.

```
var casper = require("casper").create();

var x = require("casper").selectXpath;

casper.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0");


phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;

var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;

casper.start("SOME-URL");

casper.then(function(){
  casper.capture("test.png");
  this.debugHTML();
});

casper.run();
```

I then run the code with: casperjs --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true --cookies-file=/tmp/cookies.txt JScraper.js

The --ssl-protocol=any, --ignore-ssl-errors=true and --cookies-file/... were all addded in an attempt to get this working.  Currently all I get is the return value:

> The .png that outputs is a blank 400x300 image.

The page uses https and the pages link to a directory, not directly to a file, though it loads fine in my browser.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?  I don't see any errors, just gives me a blank page.

Comment: I am currently running PhantomJS version 2.0.0

Comment: Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Also, please don't mix PhantomJS code and CasperJS code like this. You're creating a `page` which you never use afterwards. Cookies and JavaScript are enabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after playing around with this for quite some time, Artom B.'s comment finally lead me in the right direction.  CasperJS requires using a version of PhantomJS 1.8.2 or higher, but less than 2.0.0.

So I uninstalled PhantomJS, installed version 1.9.8 and it still didn't work.  So, next I uninstalled CasperJS and installed the development version and ran my script with

```
casperjs --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 --ignore-ssl-errors=true --cookies-file=/tmp/cookies.txt JScraper.js
```

This did the trick.